# iOS sqlcipher fmdb “File is encrypted or is not a database”

Tags: ios, sqlite, encryption, fmdb, sqlcipher

This [tutorial](http://www.guilmo.com/fmdb-with-sqlcipher-tutorial/) works just fine with the following pieces of code.

```
pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher'
```

...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameDefault.sqlite"];

    [self createAndCheckDatabase];

...
}
```

...

```
-(void) createAndCheckDatabase
{
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];

    if(success) return; // If file exists, dont do anything

    // if file does not exist, make a copy of the one in the Resources folder
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameDefault.sqlite"]; // File path

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil]; // Make a copy of the file in the Documents folder

    // Set the new encrypted database path to be in the Documents Folder
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *ecDB = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"encrypted.sqlite"];

    // SQL Query. NOTE THAT DATABASE IS THE FULL PATH NOT ONLY THE NAME
    const char* sqlQ = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ATTACH DATABASE '%@' AS encrypted KEY 'secretKey';",ecDB] UTF8String];

    sqlite3 *unencrypted_DB;    
    if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &unencrypted_DB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Attach empty encrypted database to unencrypted database
        sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, sqlQ, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // export database
        sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // Detach encrypted database
        sqlite3_exec(unencrypted_DB, "DETACH DATABASE encrypted;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        sqlite3_close(unencrypted_DB);
    } else {
        sqlite3_close(unencrypted_DB);
        NSAssert1(NO, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(unencrypted_DB));
    }

    self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"encrypted.sqlite"];
}
```

...

```
[db setKey:@"secretKey"]
```

...

```
   // FMDatabase
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDatabasePath]];
    [db open];
    [db setKey:@"secretKey"];

    // FMDatabaseQueue
    FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:[self getDatabasePath]];

    [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        [db setKey:@"secretKey"];
        ...
    }];
```

...

When I use the same code in my other project it works fine for encrypting the existing sqlite database. **But when I try to access table via sql select query I get the error, "File is encrypted or is not a database".** Though, no issue with the tutorial app and I can update/insert/delete/select records there. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it fixed. As mentioned the same code is acting differently so there might be something wrong with the settings. In my app, I added the SQLCipher and FMDB as follows:

```
pod 'SQLCipher', '~> 3.1'
pod 'FMDB', '~> 2.5'
```

while in that tutorial they are being added as

```
pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher'
```

Though, this pod command download the same versions of SQLCipher and FMDB as per the terminal output shown here

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing FMDB (2.5)
Installing SQLCipher (3.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

So, I changed the pod command like that of the tutorial and that error is fixed. Though, I don't know how these commands differ.

Comment: [The FMDB/SQLCipher subspec declares SQLCipher as a dependency, allowing FMDB to be compiled with the -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC flag.](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#cocoapods) More exactly, [this line](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/FMDB.podspec#L42).

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed.I think there are some inter pod dependency with FMDB & SQLCipher. I have solved this problem using below link. Now my database file encrypt successfully using SQLCipher with FMDB.... :-D

[How to Use FMDB With SQLCipher?](http://www.guilmo.com/fmdb-with-sqlcipher-tutorial/)